# node.js + nodemon, babel, & dotenv

Tags: node.js, nodemon, dotenv

How can I run a node.js app with nodemon, babel, and dotenv, so that I can use import statements in my entry file? Or is this simply not possible with nodemon?

Someone else posted this same question but no working answer was ever submitted.

Also, am I supposed to use @babel/node instead of babel-node now? The babel documentation doesn't explain.

Comment: Import explained: https://adrianmejia.com/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond/#Imports

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using a current version of nodejs, you do not need anything additional to use import statements. Just run `node entry.js`

Babel is really only useful when producing a front end javascript file or if you really want to use an experimental syntax.  Dotenv is just a library used to simplify supplying env vars to your app. Nodemon only exists to make development easier by rerunning the application when there are file changes and is not necessary.